# Modify Regex To Match String with Multiple Full Month Names And End on Hyphen

Tags: regex, date

I am using a Regex to pull dates out of a series of strings.  The format varies slightly, but it always contains the full month.  The strings usually contain two dates to represent a range like so:

```
February 1, 2020 - March 18, 2020
```

or

```
February 1st 2020 - March 18th 2020
```

And this is working great until I come across dates like:

```
June 1 - July 22, 2018
```

where a year is not presented in the "starting" part of the range because it is the same as the "ending" year.

Below is the Regex I crudely copied and applied to my code.  It is Javascript but I really think this is more of a Regex question...

```
const regex = /((\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?)(\d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)?)?((\s*[,.\-\/]\s*)\D?)?\s*((19[0-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})*/gm;

var myDateString1 = "January 8, 2020 - January 27, 2020"; // THIS WORKS GREAT!
var myDateString2 = "January 8 - January 27, 2020"; // THIS DOES NOT WORK GREAT!

var dates = myDateString1.match(regex);
// returns ["January 8, 2020","January 27, 2020"]

var dates2 = myDateString2.match(regex);
// returns ["January 8 - J"]
```

Is there a way I can modify this so if it is met with a hyphen it discontinues that given match?  So `myDateString2` would return `["January 8", "January 27, 2020"]`?

The strings sometimes have words before or after, like

```
Presented from January 8, 2020 - January 27, 2020 at such and such place
```

so I don't think simply having a regex based on the hyphen before/after would work.

Comment: Why don't you simplify it to 2 capture groups and match the specific format? https://regex101.com/r/EXYE5Y/1

Comment: Do the dates have to be valid? You could make this much simpler if they didnt have to be. And are the months always whole words? If they are you could simplify that bracket monstrosity.

Comment: The dates do not have to be valid.  I can convert them later, I just need an array which contains two dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 2 capture groups and make the pattern more specific to match the format of the strings.

The `/m` flag can be omitted as there are no anchors in the pattern.

Note that the pattern matches a date like pattern, and does not validate the date itself.

```
\b((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\s*\d\d?(?:,\s+\d{4})?)\s+[,./-]\s+\b((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\s*\d\d?,\s+\d{4})\b
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/UnWMDY/1).

```js
const regex = /\b((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\s*\d\d?(?:,\s+\d{4})?)\s+[,./-]\s+\b((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\s*\d\d?,\s+\d{4})\b/g;
const str = `January 8, 2020 - January 27, 2020
January 8 - January 27, 2020
Presented from January 8, 2020 - January 27, 2020 at such and such place
June 1 - July 22, 2018`;

console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => [m[1], m[2]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Note- original regex,  tried to be all match of forms, which is not possible like this. I reformed it to do 75% of original intent. But is fools gold et all, in the end ..

The capture groups were used for debug.
Simply taking out the hyphen  in the class and making the year optional at the end with a single `?` should get what you want.

```
/((\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?)(\d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)?)?(((\s*[,./]))?\s+(19[0-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})?/
```

https://regex101.com/r/6NiNxy/1

And replacing the capture groups  with clusters `(?: )` then giving it one more level of factoring will make it quicker.

```
/(?:\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ne?|ly?))|Feb(?:ruary)?|Ma(?:r(?:ch)?|y)|A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?(?:\d{1,2}(?:st|[nr]d|th)?)?(?:(?:\s*[,./])?\s+(?:19[0-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})?/
```

https://regex101.com/r/NTR0WD/1

```js
const regex = /(?:\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ne?|ly?))|Feb(?:ruary)?|Ma(?:r(?:ch)?|y)|A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?(?:\d{1,2}(?:st|[nr]d|th)?)?(?:(?:\s*[,./])?\s+(?:19[0-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})?/g;
var myDateString1 = "January 8, 2020 - January 27, 2020";
var myDateString2 = "January 8 - January 27, 2020";

console.log(myDateString1.match(regex));
console.log(myDateString2.match(regex));
```